# Sending And Receving packets on serial port

Tags: java, android, serial-port, usb

Hi i am trying to use serial port to send and recieve messages on android serial port.

i am us the below example but i am getting error

The import android.serial cannot be resolved.

here is code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.serial.*;

public class Serial_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_serial_);

    SerialManager Serial; 

    Serial = (SerialManager) getSystemService(Context.SERIAL_SERVICE); 

    Serial.begin("ttyUSB0", 9600);

    /* Handle Serial messages */
    SerialStatus.SerialMsgListener sl = new SerialStatus.SerialMsgListener() {
        public void onSerialMsgReceived(String sMsg) {
                /* Handle the message.. */
                Log.v("SkeletonSerial", sMsg);
            }
        };

        Serial.addSerialMsgListener(sl);
}
}
```

Comment: The Android SDK does not contain a serial port API. Did you add the required (external) library to your project?

Comment: no i have not added any api but i a am unable to find that api here is the link of example http://antipastohw.pbworks.com/w/page/41729078/How-to%20use%20a%20serial%20port%20with%20Android,%20Liquidware%20Ambrosia%20edition

Comment: SerialPort class is there in Android sources, but it's hidden API. You can use it through reflection or duplicate its classes, but it has native methods, so it's harder task.